# How to display part of an image for the specific width and height?

Tags: javascript, css, image, image-processing, imageview

Recently I participated in a web project which has a huge large of images to handle and display on web page, we know that the width and height of images end users uploaded cannot be control easily and then they are hard to display. At first, I attempted to zoom in/out the images to rearch an appropriate presentation, and I made it, but my boss is still not satisfied with my solution, the following is my way:

```
var autoResizeImage = function(maxWidth, maxHeight, objImg) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = objImg.src;

    img.onload = function() {
        var hRatio;
        var wRatio;
        var Ratio = 1;

        var w = img.width;
        var h = img.height;

        wRatio = maxWidth / w;
        hRatio = maxHeight / h;

        if (maxWidth == 0 && maxHeight == 0) {
            Ratio = 1;
        } else if (maxWidth == 0) {
            if (hRatio < 1) {
                Ratio = hRatio;
            }
        } else if (maxHeight == 0) {
            if (wRatio < 1) {
                Ratio = wRatio;
            }
        } else if (wRatio < 1 || hRatio < 1) {
            Ratio = (wRatio <= hRatio ? wRatio : hRatio);
        }

        if (Ratio < 1) {
            w = w * Ratio;
            h = h * Ratio;
        }

        w = w <= 0 ? 250 : w;
        h = h <= 0 ? 370 : h;

        objImg.height = h;
        objImg.width = w;
    };
};
```

This way is only intended to limit the max width and height for the image so that every image in album still has different width and height which are still very urgly.

And right at this minute, I know we can create a DIV and use the image as its background image, this way is too complicated and not direct I don't want to take. So I's wondering whether there is a better way to display images with the fixed width and height without presentation distortion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at something like [twitter bootstraps carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel). In this they use an image tag within a div and size it by setting the image properties to something like

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

You can see a small example in this [little fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kelaban/X9a7g/1/).

By setting height to auto it will keep the ratio intact. 
By setting max-width: 100% it will not zoom in the image past it's original size.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem follow the following steps:

1, Write a method to zoom in/out the image to the appropriate width and height you want:

```
var autoResizeImage = function(targetWidth, targetHeight, objImg) {
    if (0 >= targetWidth || 0 >= targetHeight) {
        // Ilegal parameters, just return.
        return;
    }

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = objImg.src;

    // Calculate the width and height immediately the image is loaded. 
    img.onload = function() {
        var hRatio;
        var wRatio;

        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;

        var calcWidth = width;
        var calcHeight = height;

        wRatio = targetWidth / width;
        hRatio = targetHeight / height;

        if (wRatio < hRatio) {
            calcWidth = targetWidth;
            calcHeight = (targetHeight / height) * targetHeight;
        } else {
            calcHeight = targetHeight;
            calcWidth = (targetWidth / width) * targetWidth;
        }

        objImg.width = calcWidth;
        objImg.height = calcHeight;
    };
};
```

and then call this method in its onload event like

```
<img src='PATH' onload='autoResizeImage(740, 460, this)'/>
```

2, Create a DIV outside of this image and style the width and height that you want to image displays with:

```
<div style='width: 740px; height: 460px; overflow:hidden;'></div>
```

And then the image would display with the fixed width and height you set.

Thanks for my friends from this site.